# Auto populate dashes after a several length of string problem

Tags: javascript, html

Previously I have done a useful function for user to auto populate dashes after a length of string.

To understand my scenario :

1. I have a text box for user to key in Mobile No.
2. To make the value inserted is the same format, I code a script to auto insert a dash a length of char.
3. The problem is, whenever I want to erase the inserted value, the script wont allow me as it auto populate the dash after a length of
   string unless I press the "backspace" longer then only I can erase
   the inserted value.

Here is my script for the auto inserted dash :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[name$='Mobile No. Text Box']").keyup(function(){
if ($(this).val().length == 5){ 
$(this).val($(this).val() + "-"); } 
}); });
```

and here is the image of the text box

[Mobile No. Text Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kf3BS.png)

Please help, Thank You.

Regards

Comment: you must've forgotten that when you press the "backspace" button, you are calling the key up event... if it's not an overkill to your solution, I suggest you use a library for that, or might as well handle keying "backspace" events

Comment: yes, that is why I cant find the solution on how to stop calling the function when user tried to press backspace to erase the value.. anyway I found the solution.. thank you for your response. Really appreciated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a Validation to avoid adding the "-" when user presses the backspace

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[name$='Mobile No. Text Box']").keyup(function(e){

if ($(this).val().length == 5 && e.which != 8){ 
$(this).val($(this).val() + "-"); } 
}); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="Mobile No. Text Box">
```

Comment: It works! thank you so much! but may I know, why does we use -> e.which != 8

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty libraries out there which can help you with this problem. I personally recommend this one https://github.com/text-mask

You can read through plain vanilla JavaScript usage right here https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/vanilla#readme

I believe its first example is a basic phone-number input which is exactly what you are looking for.